# How to forward the URL's all parameters through a proxy_pass with nginx?

Tags: nginx, parameters, nginx-config, proxypass

How to forward the URL's all parameters  through a proxy_pass with nginx?

Nginx config:

```
location /proxy/ {
     if ($request_method = HEAD) { return 200; }

     if ( $arg_address != "" ) {
      proxy_pass $arg_address;
      return 301 $arg_address;
      }  

     proxy_ssl_verify       off;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
 }
```

this urls works:

https://localhost/proxy/?address=https://exemple.com/transfer/file.txt ==>> https://exemple.com/transfer/file.txt

or

https://localhost/proxy/?address=https://exemple.com/transfer/file.txt?host-id=1 ==>> https://exemple.com/transfer/file.tx?host-id=1

if I add multiple parameters, it will be truncated to the first "&"

https://localhost/proxy/?address=https://exemple.com/transfer/file.txt?host-id=1&password=123456&date=xxxxxx
==>> https://exemple.com/transfer/file.txt?host-id=1

How can I transfer the entire url?

Answer (score 0):

Before we get to the answer, may I ask what do you want to achieve? Do you want to proxy the request or to generate HTTP 301 redirect? With the following construction

```
if ( $arg_address != "" ) {
    proxy_pass $arg_address;
    return 301 $arg_address;
}
```

you'll always get a redirect because the directives from [`ngx_http_rewrite_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) are executed **before** any others, so the `proxy_pass` directive is useless here. `ngx_http_rewrite_module` is very special and different from most of the other modules. Although nginx configuration in general is declarative, rewrite module evaluates its instructions imperatively. This is always a source of confusion for every nginx novice. You can read more about the rewrite module internal implementation [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#internals).

If you want to proxy the request instead of generating a redirect, you'll need to remove `return` and add a [`resolver`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver) directive to your configuration. [Here](http://www.nginx-discovery.com/2011/05/day-51-proxypass-and-resolver.html) you can read why it is required.

**A "dirty hack" solution**

Being that said, get back to the question. Of course, when nginx receives the request

```
https://localhost/proxy/?address=https://example.com/transfer/file.txt?host-id=1&password=123456&date=20210520
```

`arg_NAME` variables will be filled the following way:

```
arg_address => https://example.com/transfer/file.txt?host-id=1
arg_password => 123456
arg_date => 20210520
```

It is correct and expected behavior.

What you can do to preserve all the other query arguments? The most simple is to assume that all query arguments following the `address` one are subject to pass to the upstream and use a [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) directive to get the required string:

```
map $args $address {
    ~(?:^|&)(address=.*)    $1;
}

server {
    ...
    location /proxy/ {
        ...
        if ($address) {
            # 'proxy_pass $address' or 'return 301 $address' here
        }  
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Here is more strict check where we take the rest of the query string only if there is a question mark after `address` query parameter and only `$arg_address` value otherwise:

```
map $args $address {
    ~(?:^|&)(address=[^&?]+\?.*)    $1;
    default                         $arg_address;
}
```

**Reliable solution**

While the answer above is generally workable, I'd rather try to design my proxy solution using [URL encoding](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-2.1) on `address` query argument to avoid [reserved characters](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-2.2) usage as part of the query argument value. The above request being URL-encoded would look like

```
https://localhost/proxy/?address=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ftransfer%2Ffile.txt%3Fhost-id%3D1%26password%3D123456%26date%3D20210520
```

The bad thing is that "vanilla" nginx doesn't have an ability to URL-decode an arbitrary string. However it can be done using [OpenResty](https://openresty.org/)/[lua-nginx-module](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module):

```
location /proxy/ {
    ...
    set_by_lua_block $address { return ngx.unescape_uri(ngx.var.arg_address) }
    if ($address) {
        # 'proxy_pass $address' or 'return 301 $address' here
    }  
    ...
}
```

or [`set-misc-nginx-module`](https://github.com/openresty/set-misc-nginx-module):

```
location /proxy/ {
    ...
    if ($arg_address) {
        set_unescape_uri $address $arg_address;
        # 'proxy_pass $address' or 'return 301 $address' here
    }  
    ...
}
```

Perhaps the same can be done using [njs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/njs/index.html), but I didn't use it and can't give you an example.